# How to update last record with second lat results [SQLServer]

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-update

I want to update the last entry of the table with Pass/Fail result from the second last row. And the query need to didnt fail if only one row is in the table.

Here is the code what i have, but ist only update with the first entrys and not the the second last entrys. thx for help

```
UPDATE DB.dbo.Testergebnisse 
SET 
    Pass = (
        SELECT TOP 1 Pass
        FROM DB.dbo.Testergebnisse
        WHERE 
            TestergebnisID != ( 
                SELECT MAX(TestergebnisID) FROM DB.dbo.Testergebnisse 
            )
            AND TestaufstellungID = 3166 
        ORDER BY TestergebnisID DESC
    ),
    Fail = (
        SELECT TOP 1 Fail
        FROM DB.dbo.Testergebnisse
        WHERE 
            TestergebnisID != ( 
                SELECT MAX(TestergebnisID)  FROM DB.dbo.Testergebnisse 
            ) 
            AND TestaufstellungID = 3166 
            ORDER BY TestergebnisID DESC
    )
WHERE 
    DB.dbo.Testergebnisse.TestergebnisID = ( 
        SELECT TOP 1 TestergebnisID 
        FROM DB.dbo.Testergebnisse 
        WHERE TestaufstellungID =  3166 
        ORDER BY TestergebnisID DESC
    )
```

SQL Server Version: 9.0.5057

Comment: Show some example data so it is clear what you need. All we have to go off is your unclear explanation and some SQL that doesn't do what you need

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure I'm following. Given data like this:

```
TestergebnisID TestaufstellungID Pass        Fail
-------------- ----------------- ----------- -----------
1              1                 10          12
2              1                 5           6
3              1                 3           4
4              2                 0           0
```

You want to update the row with TestergebnisID = 3 with Pass and Fail from record with TestergebnisID = 2 and that's it? Or should record 2 be updated with data from record 1 too?

In case of the former, this should do the trick:

```
;WITH rec AS
(
    SELECT this.TestaufstellungID 
         -- most recent for the given test run
         , MAX(this.TestergebnisID) AS LastTestergebnisID 
         -- find the previous 
         , PrevTestergebnisID =
           (SELECT MAX(prev.TestergebnisID) 
              FROM Testergebnisse prev 
             WHERE prev.TestaufstellungID = this.TestaufstellungID  
               AND prev.TestergebnisID < MAX(this.TestergebnisID )
           ) 
      FROM Testergebnisse this
     GROUP BY this.TestaufstellungID
)
UPDATE mostRecent
   SET Pass = prev.Pass
     , Fail = prev.Fail
  FROM Testergebnisse mostRecent
  JOIN rec
    ON rec.LastTestergebnisID = mostRecent.TestergebnisID 
  JOIN Testergebnisse prev
    ON prev.TestergebnisID = rec.PrevTestergebnisID
```

Gives:

```
TestergebnisID TestaufstellungID Pass        Fail
-------------- ----------------- ----------- -----------
1              1                 10          12
2              1                 5           6
3              1                 5           6       <-- 1 row affected
4              2                 0           0
```

If you want all of them to be updated with their predecessors' values, then:

```
;WITH rec AS
(
    SELECT this.TestaufstellungID 
         -- most recent for the given test run
         , this.TestergebnisID
         -- find the previous 
         , PrevTestergebnisID =
           (SELECT MAX(prev.TestergebnisID) 
              FROM Testergebnisse prev 
             WHERE prev.TestaufstellungID = this.TestaufstellungID  
               AND prev.TestergebnisID < this.TestergebnisID
           ) 
      FROM Testergebnisse this
)
UPDATE mostRecent
   SET Pass = prev.Pass
     , Fail = prev.Fail
  FROM Testergebnisse mostRecent
  JOIN rec
    ON rec.TestergebnisID = mostRecent.TestergebnisID 
  JOIN Testergebnisse prev
    ON prev.TestergebnisID = rec.PrevTestergebnisID
```

This will update rows 2 (from 1) & 3 (from 2):

```
TestergebnisID TestaufstellungID Pass        Fail
-------------- ----------------- ----------- -----------
1              1                 10          12
2              1                 10          12       <--
3              1                 5           6        <--
4              2                 0           0
```

Answer (score 0):

If I followed you  correctly, it should be possible to simplify the query by using an updatable Common Table Expression, like:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT 
        TestergebnisID, 
        TestaufstellungID,
        Pass, 
        Fail,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY TestaufstellungID ORDER BY TestergebnisID DESC) rn,
        LEAD(Pass)    OVER(PARTITION BY TestaufstellungID ORDER BY TestergebnisID DESC) prev_pass,
        LEAD(Fail)    OVER(PARTITION BY TestaufstellungID ORDER BY TestergebnisID DESC) prev_fail
    FROM DB.dbo.Testergebnisse
    WHERE TestaufstellungID = 3166
)
UPDATE cte 
SET Pass = prev_pass, Fail = prev_fail 
WHERE rn = 1
```

The CTE uses window functions to:

- rank each record `ROW_NUMBER()` by descending `TestergebnisID` (using `ROW_NUMBER()`)
- retrieve the `Pass` and `Fail` of the previous record, `TestergebnisID`-wise (using `LEAD()`)
- operations are performed within groups of records having the same `TestaufstellungID` (you can just remove the `WHERE` clause in the CTE to have all `TestaufstellungID` processed instead of just one of them)

Then, the main query simply selects the most record record (`rn = 1`) and assigns `Pass` and `Fail` from the values in the previous record

Comment: Iam sry i cant use this because i use sql server 2005 SQL Server Version: 9.0.5057

Comment: @Daniel: right, CTE and `ROW_NUMBER()` are available starting SQL-Server 2008 only... So indeed this solution will not work on SQL-Server 2005. This is really an old version, wouln't you consider upgrading sometimes?

Comment: sure i would but its not in my Hands :(

Comment: CTE and Row number are available in 2005. It is LAG that isn't available there

Comment: Of course this should be LEAD and the same DESC order in all three ORDER BY.

Comment: @dnoeth: ah yes, I think that you are right... I updated my answer... Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If partitioning is unavailable, you can insert the last two rows into a temp table. That way, your max is the last row and your min is the second to last row.

This gives you the ID for the value you want to set from and the ID of the row you want to update, along with the values to use.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Temp') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE ##SourceValues
SELECT TOP 2 
TestergebnisID,Pass, Fail
INTO #Temp FROM Testergebnisse (NOLOCK)
WHERE TestaufstellungID = 3166
ORDER BY TestergebnisID DESC
DECLARE @LastId INT = (SELECT MAX(TestergebnisID) FROM #Temp)
DECLARE @SecondToLast INT = (SELECT MIN(TestergebnisID) FROM #Temp)
UPDATE DB.dbo.Testergebnisse SET Pass = (SELECT Pass FROM #Temp WHERE TestergebnisID = @SecondToLast) WHERE TestergebnisID = @LastID
UPDATE DB.dbo.Testergebnisse SET Fail = (SELECT Fail FROM #Temp WHERE TestergebnisID = @SecondToLast) WHERE TestergebnisID = @LastID
```